# When adding a new object to mydbcontext, one of the object members (a List<>) is set as null after I query for the object later

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

So after I set up my object to be set in `MyDbContext db` like so:

```
Article newBlogPost = new Article()
{
    ArticleComments = new List<Comment>()
};

db.BlogPosts.Add(newBlogPost);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I access this same object later in a different view, like so:

```
model.articleList = db.BlogPosts.ToList();
```

When I go into debugging mode, I check the value of `model.articleList` and it is simply `null`, instead of a newly instantiated `List<Article>`. It is as if when I add this `List<Article>` object to the database, it disposes of it as soon as I call `db.SaveChanges();` Note that I have other simpler attributes in this `Article` object like strings, ints etc. that save correctly.

Does `DbContext` not allow containers to be stored inside? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: do you load complex types from db ? i guyss you are not loading them from database: see db.BlogPosts.Include("ArticleComments").First();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working in C# we're so used to dealing with objects and their inner state that it may be a mind-bending truth that **ORMs don't save collections**.

Fundamentally this is because relational databases don't store collections (contrary to object data databases). In an RDBMS, a parent record is a stand-alone entity. A child record 'has' the reference to its parent. Conversely, in an object space the parent contains, 'has', its children and the children can be totally oblivious of their parent. This is the 'chasm' an ORM crosses for us.

Now consider a few things about EF:

- When you query a `DbSet` (like `db.BlogPosts`), EF populates `new` objects from database data. It doesn't reuse objects that it has cached. Cached objects, if any, are in the `DbSet.Local` collection.
- When you get objects from the database, EF doesn't create collections for their collection properties, unless you also load these collections, for instance by `Include` or lazy loading.
- So unloaded collections are `null`, unless you initialize these collections yourself, e.g. in the object's constructor.

So `db.BlogPosts.ToList()` creates brand new objects. Any information about non-null collections they had when they were saved is lost, because there is no way to store this information.

Comment: Looking back at this I see that this is only the "dry" explanation of what happens, not what you can do about it if you want. I think you should add the `virtual` modifier to the `ArticleComments` collection member. This will enable EF to create a proxy `Article` object that's ready for lazy loading, so it *does* have an initialized collection (but empty until loaded).